# My Service says it's running but its state is unclear—it doesn't appear to be bound

Tags: java, android, service, binding

I have a Service that I want to be both bound and started in Foreground mode. It includes this:

```
public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId ) {
        super.onStartCommand( intent, flags, startId ); 
        if( DEBUG ) Log.d( TAG, "onStartCommand() entered");  // never prints
        runningNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder( getApplicationContext(), "Channel 1" )
                .setContentTitle( "PID Service Running" )
                .setCategory( CATEGORY_SERVICE )
                .setOngoing( true )
                .build();
        startForeground( SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, runningNotification );
```

I start it in my Activity (have tried both `onCreate()` and `onStart()`):

```
bindThermoServiceIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ThermocoupleService.class );
serviceComponentName = getApplicationContext().startService( bindThermoServiceIntent );  // bind to it AND start it
if( DEBUG ) {  // seems to never fail to start
    if( serviceComponentName != null ) Log.d( TAG, "Service running with ComponentName " + serviceComponentName.toShortString() );  // looks OK
    else throw new NullPointerException( "Attempt to start Service failed" );
}
if( !( serviceBound = bindService( bindThermoServiceIntent, /*ServiceConnection*/ this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE ) ) )
    throw new RuntimeException( TAG + ": bindService() call in onCreate() failed" );  // no exception
```

It always logs "Service running" with the right `ComponentName`, but the log statement in `onStartCommand()` never prints.

And later, when I try to bind the Activity to the Service, I always get a `null` reference for the Service. It appears that `onServiceConnected()` is not being called since the log statement doesn't print:

```
public void onServiceConnected( ComponentName className, IBinder service ) {
        Log.d( TAG, "Entering onServiceConnected()" );
        // We've bound to Service, cast the IBinder and get Service instance
        thermoBinder = (ThermocoupleService.LocalBinder) service;
        thermoServiceRef = thermoBinder.getService();
        if( thermoServiceRef == null ) throw new RuntimeException( TAG
                + ": onServiceConnected returned null from getService()" );
        Log.d( TAG, "Finished onServiceConnected()" );
    }
```

When I try to use `thermoServiceRef` in the Activity's `onResume()`, I get a `NullPointerException`.

Basically all this code is adapted straight from the Android examples, and I can't figure out where it's going wrong. I've used similar code in other apps that worked, though this is the first time I've tried to use Foreground mode for a Service.

It now occurs to me that this could be related to another problem I'd noticed: when I try to unbind the Service in the Activity's `onDestroy()`, I've been getting a message that it wasn't connected.

Update: here's the Service declaration in the Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".ThermocoupleService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:description="@string/service_description" >
</service>
```

Comment: Since your service apparently hasn't attempted to move into foreground mode (you're not seeing an icon in the notification bar), "foreground" can't be the problem. That neither `onServiceConnected()` or `onStartCommand()` ever execute strongly suggests your service has never started (`onCreate()`). I assume this an "in-process" `Service`? Based on my experience, this is basically impossible, unless you swallow an exception you're not supposed to, or if you manage to hang the UI thread in some really creative way.

Comment: Don't know what an "in-process" Service is. The Service is supposed to keep running in the background, collecting data from a peripheral, even if the Activity is destroyed. I was considering trying to start it in the Application's `onCreate()`; is this allowed and a good idea?

Comment: Also I don't understand how the Service can not be started if `.startService()` is returning the correct `ComponentName`.

Comment: If the `Service` is part of your same .apk, then it's in-process. That's generally the case but this is unusual behavior so I wanted to make sure. Most people have trouble keeping Services running, but there never seems to be a problem getting them started... You can certainly start it up in `Activity.onCreate()` if you want. So... `Service.onCreate()` is not executing?

Comment: Now's probably a good time to make sure the service is registered properly in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Boy, this is strange! I moved `.startService()` from the Activity's `onCreate()` to the Application's `onCreate()`, and it still returns the right `ComponentName`, indicating it's started. But that's the last I ever hear from it: even logging statements in the Service's `onCreate()` are not being executed. I gave up trying to use binding and instead made the Service store a reference to itself in the Application singleton. But it's `null`. (I've added the Manifest code to my question, showing that it is in fact registered.)

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need to call `startService()` because `bindService()` will prompt the service to start equally well. I think you're going to need to post some more code so we can get an MCVE going here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182535/discussion-between-robert-lewis-and-greeble31).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look at your entire project on GitHub, I think I can point out what went wrong.

You've incorrectly assumed that `startService()`/`bindService()` create the `Service` synchronously. It looks like your app will crash in `onResume()` if the `Service` reference isn't yet populated. That's not enough time for Android to create the `Service`. If it hadn't crashed, `Service.onCreated()` would have be called shortly after `onResume()` returned.

TL;DR: Expect asynchronous `Service` creation. ("Asynchronous" isn't quite the right word here, b/c it does all take place on the UI thread. Maybe "Delayed" would be better).

Comment: I cannot explain why the Service would appear to start up later, after a crash. If somehow `Activity.onCreate()` got called without an `onResume()`, it might be possible. If it appeared that the RxJava stuff was somehow continuing after the app crash, I would suggest that's an illusion caused by in-flight HTTP requests or something like that.

Comment: Wow, great tip! I need to think about it, but first thought is: one of my `Observable`s only emits an item every 40 seconds and I'm wondering if that could somehow hang the `Service` creation until it gets going. Should I create some kind of semaphore that waits for the `onServiceConnected()` callback?

Comment: "could somehow hang the `Service` creation until it gets going" <-- I don't think so. Either your app is ANRing, or the `Service` will be created right away. Semaphore is not the right word but you must somehow establish a "happens before" relationship -- that is to say, you must not attempt any operations that depend on the `Service` until you have a reference to the `Service`. So, it's best to kick things off inside of `onServiceConnected()`.

Comment: Huge progress! I bind the `Service` in `Activity.onStart()` and then defer further action to the `onServiceConnected()` callback. The log now shows the expected steps in connecting the `Service`. One problem: `Activity.onResume()` needs to have the `Service` connected, and I don't know how to make it wait for it without an ANR (spinlocking on the service reference not being `null` doesn't work, presumably because it's all running on the same thread). Haven't figured out how to handle this yet.

Comment: "presumably because it's all running on the same thread" <-- Correct. You're not going to be able to use the service in `onResume()` -- at least not the first time it's called. Your only option is to track the "resumed" state of the app, and your `Service's` "connected" state, and defer your `appInstance.thermocoupleService.tempHistRelay.subscribe()` call until both items are true. (When I write `Service` connection code, I tend to avoid making assumptions about whether `onResume()` or `onServiceConnected()` will be called first. I just check the state each time it changes.)

Comment: Maybe I can create another `Observable` that emits the "service connected" state (easy to do on a different thread) and subscribe to it in `onResume()`. I've used the excellent `RxAndroidBle` Bluetooth LE library quite a bit and it has a similar Observable that tracks the Bluetooth connection state.